# Bootstrap Nav-tab show hide content

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the app that I am building to learn Rails and JS, I want to use tab-navigation.

This is my tab-navigation pointing to 3 sections. I am now looking to create the JavaScript. How to I approach this when clicking the tabs and set class active to the clicked `<li>` while display the respective section?

I can't do getElementById or so. So, I need something like this structure:

```
$("li.presentation").on("click", function(event) { ...
    $(...).class("active");
    $(...).toggle();
};
```

All help appreciated!

```
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1">Details</a></li>
    <% unless @annotation.new_record? %>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2">Tags</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2">Comments</a></li>
    <% end -%>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Sections

```
<section id="tab1" class="tab1">
    <p>Section 1 content here </p>
</section>
<section id="tab2" class="tab2">
    <p>Section 2 content here </p>
</section>
<section id="tab3" class="tab3">
    <p>Section 1 content here </p>
</section>
<section id="tab3" class="tab3">
    <p>Section 3 content here </p>
</section>
```

This is my css

```css
.tab1 {
    display: block;
}

.tab2 {
    display: none;
}

.tab3 {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to roll out your own custom `JavaScript` and `css` to accomplish this. You can use `Bootstrap's` built-in `data-toggle="tab"` attribute in your tab anchors.

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <!-- add data-toggle attribute to the anchors -->
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a live demo:
http://www.bootply.com/ZSu8N3bB03

Comment: is there something like that for tables? to expand collapse rows?

Comment: @DimitrideRuiter not that I know of. I've used this table http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/ and it works well. You might want to check it out and see.

Comment: Thanks, the concept is still valid for latest bootstrap, trying with V5. I wasted almost one day trying to make it work with js and css. Also, just a point to note is that href of the anchor should be same to the id of the divs (i.e. without the hash #) then it works smoothly!! :)

Comment: @3AK I’m glad this answer helped even for new new version of bootstrap. Thanks for the recommendation on the `#` I tried It out and it works as well! In the docs use the `#` though.  Time to dig into bootstrap and see what’s up 