# Tabs with Bootstrap and Thymeleaf

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I am trying to create tabs with content. Here is the HTML code. When I first load the page Main tab is active, next when I click Names no action happens and content panel does not open.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ID=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-flat nav-justified">
      <li class="active"><a th:href="@{#flatmain}" data-toggle="tab">Main</a></li>
      <li><a th:href="@{#flatnames}" data-toggle="tab">Names</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
      <!-- flat-main -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="flatmain">
        <div class="row"  style="padding: 1px;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Main</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input class="form-control" id="disabledMain" type="text" placeholder="Main Value" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- flat-names -->
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="flatnames">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 11px;">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input class="form-control" id="disabledScac" type="text" placeholder="26 Character Value" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to switch between the tabs using bootstrap and thymeleaf. My tab names are static and they remain same all the time. Only Content panel need to change.

Comment: Commenting on an old question but this might help someone - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142438/1936319 Also, see my comments for the latest bootstrap version v5.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check the error console from time to time. It's wonderful (most of the time) at giving you feedback about where your page breaks, if it can't load resources, etc.

Loading up your page on an HTTPS connection produces the following error logs:

[image: error console]

It appears that some or all of your scripts aren't loading.

Comment: I modified the URL to the following. Still action is not active https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: It's the jquery url you need to modify.